# Matrix comprising columns of identity

Tags: python, numpy

I want to implement the following in python. Given a vector v of length N with each entry taking values in the set of integers 0,1,2,...,d, I want to create a new vector w of length d, that stores in the ith location the number of occurrences of the digit i in v. I assume knowledge of d, N and v.

As an example, suppose d = 3 and N=5, and v = (0,0,1,3,2). Then I want w[0] = 2, w[1] = 1, w[2] = 1, w[3] = 1, i.e. w = (2,1,1,1).

I have included my attempt below. My question is can I do it more efficiently using inbuilt numpy functions, and in particular, avoid the for loop over N? I will need to use this function multiple times in a long iterative simulation so I would like to optimise it.

My attempt:

```
import numpy as np

d = 3
N = 5
v = np.array([0,0,1,3,2])
ID = np.eye(d+1)

w = np.zeros(N)

for i in range(0,N):
    w[i] = np.sum(v==i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly [`bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html):

```
w = np.bincount(v, minlength=d+1)
```

Out:

```
array([2, 1, 1, 1])
```